# Python 3.5.1 Pip install error on mac

Tags: python

Installed Python 3.5.1 on Mac. When I try to download a module from Python's standard library such as pip install BeautifulSoup, I receive the error below:

```
Collecting BeautifulSoup
```

Using cached BeautifulSoup-3.2.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
      File "/private/var/folders/bz/2h0jcnq54pzcvjp2x0mhrc6r0000gn/T/pip-build-b_z00926/BeautifulSoup/setup.py", line 22
        print "Unit tests have failed!"
                                      ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

```
----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/bz/2h0jcnq54pzcvjp2x0mhrc6r0000gn/T/pip-build-b_z00926/BeautifulSoup/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That appears to be an old version of BeautifulSoup. Try this instead:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Comment: wow, that was simple. Thanks for that... I made this issue way more complicated than it actually was. SMH

Answer (score 0):

the missing parentheses part might suggest that pip uses python2 by default when you actually need python3

a simple workaround:

```
python3 -m pip install beautifulsoup # or beautifulsoup4
```

that has the same effect as pip install, but explicitly specifies which python to use

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pip2` (for Python 2) or `pip3` (for Python 3) instead of just `pip`. It might be using the wrong version of `pip` for the Python version you are trying to use.